# Tab character not recognized in Servlet eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am using servlets in Eclipse and trying to retrieve a result set and want to seperate each of the column retrieved from result set by using tab indentation.I have tried using \t, \n. But it is displaying the output in browser with only one space between the columns, even-though I use any special character.

```
  while (rs.next())
  {
  out.print(rs.getString(1) + rs.getString(2) + '\t' +rs.getString(3)+'\t'+rs.getString(4)+"<br>");             
   }
```

I am using Glassfish server and Eclipse IDE

Comment: This is a HTML-issue.  First write a plain HTML file doing what you want to do, and then write the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab characters are rendered as a single space in HTML.
You need to put it inside pre formatted text tags

```
out.print("<pre>");
while (rs.next()) {
    out.print(rs.getString(1) + rs.getString(2) + '\t' +rs.getString(3)+'\t'+rs.getString(4)+'\n');             
}
out.print("</pre>");
```

or make HTML table out of it:

```
out.print("<table>");
while (rs.next()) {
    out.print("<tr><td>" + rs.getString(1) + rs.getString(2) + "</td><td>" +rs.getString(3)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(4)+"</td></tr>");             
}
out.print("</table>");
```

Comment: Hello anttix, thank you very much.Actually, I have searched for it a lot and could finally get one solution that worked out.